# Searchable treeview tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to code a searchable `ttk.Treeview`; however, my code does not behave properly. When I type in and click search nothing happens. What should be improved so the searched items are highlighted when I type in?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("Medicine database")

def add():
    tree.insert("",END,values=("",e1.get()))

def search(item=''):
    children = tree.get_children(item)
    for child in children:
        text = tree.item(child, 'text')
        if text.startswith(e1.get()):
            tree.selection_set(child)
            return True
        else:
            res = search(child)
            if res:
                return True

lb1 = Label(root,text="Search:")
lb1.grid(row =0,column=0,padx=10,pady=10,sticky=W)
e1=Entry(root,width=15)
e1.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=10,sticky=E,rowspan=1)
btn = Button(root,text="search",width=10,command=search)
btn.grid(row =0,column=0,padx=10,pady=10,rowspan=2)
btn1 = Button(root,text="add",width=10,command=add)
btn1.grid(row =1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10,rowspan=2)
#treeview
tree = ttk.Treeview(root,height=25)
tree["columns"]=("one","two","three","four")
tree.column("one",width=120)
tree.column("two",width=160)
tree.column("three",width=130)
tree.column("four",width=160)
tree.heading("one", text="Numer seryjny leku")
tree.heading("two", text="Nazwa Leku")
tree.heading("three", text="Ampułki/Tabletki")
tree.heading("four",text="Data ważności")
tree["show"]="headings"
tree.grid(row=0,column=2,rowspan=6,pady=20)

root.geometry("840x580")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please share what you've done to debug this. For example, have you verified that `text` is what you think it is inside of `search`? (hint: it's not)

Comment: You should search on the `values` field instead of `text` field of each item in the treeview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it was, your `search` method did nothing.

First, you probably need to have an `entry` for adding items and another for searching them.

Then, in the `search` method, you  must retrieve the query from the `search entry`, match it with then `tree children values`, and return (here we will print) the values if you find a match, and **highlight** them in the `Treeview`.

[image]

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def add():
    value = add_entry.get()
    values.append(value)
    tree.insert("", tk.END, values=(f'#{len(values)}', value, 'more', 'moar'))


def search():
    query = search_entry.get()
    selections = []
    for child in tree.get_children():
        if query in tree.item(child)['values']:
            print(tree.item(child)['values'])
            selections.append(child)
    print('search completed')
    tree.selection_set(selections)


values = []

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Medicine database")

lb1 = tk.Label(root, text="Search:")
lb1.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.W)
search_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=15)
search_entry.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.E, rowspan=1)
btn = tk.Button(root, text="search", width=10, command=search)
btn.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, rowspan=2)

add_lb = tk.Label(root, text="add:")
add_lb.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.W)
add_entry = tk.Entry(root, width=15)
add_entry.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10, sticky=tk.E, rowspan=1)
btn1 = tk.Button(root, text="add", width=10, command=add)
btn1.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10, rowspan=2)

# treeview
tree = ttk.Treeview(root, height=25)
tree["columns"] = ("one", "two", "three", "four")
tree.column("one", width=120)
tree.column("two", width=160)
tree.column("three", width=130)
tree.column("four", width=160)
tree.heading("one", text="Numer seryjny leku")
tree.heading("two", text="Nazwa Leku")
tree.heading("three", text="Ampułki/Tabletki")
tree.heading("four", text="Data ważności")
tree["show"]="headings"
tree.grid(row=0, column=2, rowspan=6, pady=20)

root.geometry("840x580")


if __name__ == '__main__':

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ok bu if I type in search box name with lower letters it searches nothing. after or      
 if query in tree.item(child)['values'] or query.lower() in tree.item(child)['values']:
                selections.append(child)
        tree.selection_set(selections)

Comment: I don't understand your comment.

Comment: for example an item in table starts with upper letter and I type a word in search entry with lower letter and it does not search a a word with upper letter.

Comment: if query.capitalize() in tree.item(child)['values'] or query.lower() in tree.item(child)['values']:

Comment: Yes, your question was about highlighting the results of a query in the `Treeview` widget. I answered that. You can change, tweak, adapt how the search is conducted to suit your neds.

Comment: Thanks man, but if I would like to sort alphabeticaly rows after I add to tree items, I tried to add method to list like this: sorted(values) or values.sort() but it didnt work.

Comment: Sorting and searching are two different topics - please ask a new question.

Comment: I gave a question but found no constructive helpI tried couple solution by myself but it didn;t work. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62657896/sorting-items-in-treeview-after-adding-tkinter