# Sorting items in treeview after adding tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I've got a question about alphabetically sorting rows after inserting them to tree. I tried to add method data.sort() by adding or sorted(data) but it didnt work. Or is there any way to sort alphabetically items with one click button?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()
root.title("Medicine database")

def add():
    data = tree.insert("",END,values=("",e1.get()))
    data.sort()
    or sorted(data)
Or:
def sort():
    for i in tree.getchildren():
        tree.item(sorted(item))['values']

e1=Entry(root,width=15)
e1.grid(row=0,column=1,padx=10,pady=10,sticky=E,rowspan=1)

btn1 = Button(root,text="add",width=10,command=add)
btn1.grid(row =1,column=0,padx=10,pady=10,rowspan=2)


#treeview
tree = ttk.Treeview(root,height=25)
tree["columns"]=("one","two","three","four")
tree.column("one",width=120)
tree.column("two",width=160)
tree.column("three",width=130)
tree.column("four",width=160)
tree.heading("one", text="Numer seryjny leku")
tree.heading("two", text="Nazwa Leku")
tree.heading("three", text="Ampułki/Tabletki")
tree.heading("four",text="Data ważności")
tree["show"]="headings"
tree.grid(row=0,column=2,rowspan=6,pady=20)

root.geometry("840x580")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Maybe this question helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032152/python-ttk-treeview-sort-numbers

Comment: I tried this code eaelier, but it didnt help. I just want to sort rows alphabetically.

Comment: You can adapt the function to sort rows alphabetically, just sort the list alphabetically and then use the same way as in this code to reorder the rows

Comment: I tried also use this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1966929/tk-treeview-column-sort/30724912#30724912 but it doesn't work :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting a treeview is done the following way:

1. Collect the data from all the rows in a list.
2. Sort the list.
3. Move the items in the treeview to be in the same order as in the list.

Adapting the code from the answers of [python ttk treeview sort numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22032152/python-ttk-treeview-sort-numbers), this gives:

```
def sort():
    rows = [(tree.item(item, 'values'), item) for item in tree.get_children('')]
    # if you want to sort according to a single column:
    # rows = [(tree.set(item, column), item) for item in tree.get_children('')]
    rows.sort()

    # rearrange items in sorted positions
    for index, (values, item) in enumerate(rows):
        tree.move(item, '', index)
```

Just use the `sort()` function as a button's command to sort the treeview.

Edit: To sort alphabetically rows according to the value in column 'two' and regardless of capitalization:

```
def sort():
    rows = [(tree.set(item, 'two').lower(), item) for item in tree.get_children('')]
    rows.sort()

    for index, (values, item) in enumerate(rows):
        tree.move(item, '', index)
```

Comment: I'ts great but it doesn't sort the tree in alphabeticall order according to name of medicines. When I add new row it chenges order items every time

Comment: If you want to sort by column, you need to comment out the `rows = ...` line and uncomment the one that does the single column sorting, this was written in the code's comments. I couldn't guess which column you wanted to sort alphabetically so I did it for all values.  Replace `column` by `'two' ` if the medicine name is in column 'two'.

Comment: it raises an error " res = tk.call(*(args + options))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-two"  "

Comment: but if I have elements with capital letters or lower letters. I know the words with capital letters have priority and these with lower are on the bottom of the list and how to do if it doen't matter to how the words are written?

Comment: You can use `.lower()` on each name to ensure there are all lower case before sorting, see my edit.